# Setting Wordpress File Permissions to avoid hackers

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to avoid hackers by restricting (or deleting) wp-admin in wordpress? A lot of us use Wordpress for creating simple static webpage, so I thing there should be a way to just restricting access and then just update when the client asks for changes.

Comment: Most WordPress hacks don't happen from a user poking around in wp-admin manually. It's usually something automated against known vulnerabilities and wouldn't always require the admin code to even exist. If you want a static site, use something like Jekyll and host it somewhere static like S3.

Comment: After studying a lot, I found that restrict permissions to 0555 in wp-content, wp-admin and wp-includes helps a lot in reducing hacking attacks. Any opinions?